# Does MVC apply to a simple webapp that takes two numbers from an HTML form, adds them together and spits them back out on a new webpage?

Tags: servlets, model-view-controller

I am having trouble grasping the MVC model. Does/Can the MVC model apply to my very simple webapp example? (Assume it uses a server to calculate and not javascript.) If it does, what is the model, what is the controller and what is the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it applies.

The controller would be a servlet. Its role would be to get the numbers as request parameters, parse them, validate them, and compute the sum. If there is a validation problem, it would store an error message in a request attribute, and forward to the JSP page displaying the form, with the error message. If there is no problem, it would store the result in a request attribute and forward to another JSP displaying the result.

The model would be the two operands and the result of the computation: a simple Integer or Double in this case. It would also be the error message in case of a validation error.

The views would be the JSP containing the form, and populating the fields with the two operands, as well as the JSP displaying the result.

So you have the classical 3 components: the controller which handles inputs, creates a model and forwards to a view. The model which holds the data to display. The view which generates the HTML markup displaying the model.

Comment: People talk about keeping MVCs separate. So how would that manifest itself in this simple project? Would that involve having a servlet class and an addition class along with the JSP pages?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "keeping MVCs separate". The servlet is the controller (one class). The model is a bean holding the result and operands for example (one class). The view is the JSP.